# UICollectionViewCell frame is offset if created outside of -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Tags: ipad, uicollectionview, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating some `UICollectionViewCell`'s when the view loads in a method like this:

```
- (void)cachePageCells
{
    if(!_cellCache)
        _cellCache = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]];

    [pages enumerateObjectsWithOptions:0 usingBlock:^(MMGPage *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:0];
        MMGCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCELL forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIView *view = obj.view;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:pageview];

        [_cellCache addObject:cell];
    }];
}
```

This creates a `cell` with an origin of (0, -10), printing out the object in the debugger shows this:

```
(lldb) po cell
<MMGIssuePageCell: 0x156f4df0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 -10; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x156f4e80>>
```

If if use the same code in the `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method it created a cell with the correct origin of (0, 0).

If I correct the offset by reseting the frame, using something like this:

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
```

It breaks the collection view and cells jump about.

Incidentally, the `bounds` of the cell are (0 0; 768 1024).

This is running on an iPad under [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7).

Comment: Instead of move the cell, did you tried moving the cell.contentView?

Comment: Can you explain why you need these outside `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`?